# How to rotate image view?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, drawimage, mirror

I'm having problems while trying to rotate a picture with java android canvas.drawImage. I'm doing a little game, and I'm painting different pictures on the screen using my *drawImage* function. However now I want to rotate some little images, I have created a function called *drawMirroredImage* for this. However now this little images don't appear on the same place.

Here is my code:

```
public void drawImage(Image Image, int x, int y) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage) Image).bitmap, x, y, null);
}

public void drawMirroredImage(Image Image, int x, int y) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.scale(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    canvas.drawBitmap(((AndroidImage) Image).bitmap, x - canvas.getWidth(), y, null);
    canvas.restore();   
}
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Lot of thanks for helping

Comment: You should not use scale() to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code for rotating image view.

```
    Matrix mx=new Matrix();
myimageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX); 
mx.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
myimageView.setImageMatrix(mx);
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm a little bit noob and I don't have an image view... I'm using the function written in this post..